# PUT/Copy With PHP, REST, Flex, and Amazon S3

Tags: php, apache-flex, rest, amazon-s3, put

I have been trying for weeks to properly format a `REST request` to the `Amazon AWS S3 API` using the available examples on the web but have been unable to even successfully connect.

I have found the code to generate a signature, found the proper method for formatting the "string to encode", and the `http headers`. I have worked my way through the `signatureDoesNotMatch` errors just to get a `Anonymous users can not perform copy functions, Please authenticate` message.

I have a working copy of an `Adobe Flex` application that successfully uploads files, but with their "original" file name. The point of using the `REST` with the `Amazon API` is to perform a `PUT` (copy) of the file, just so I can rename it to something my back end system can use.

If I could find a way to get this `REST` submission to work, or perhaps a way to specify a "new" filename within `Flex` while uploading I could avoid this whole `REST` situation all together.

If anyone has successfully performed a `PUT/Copy` command on the `Amazon API` via `REST` I would be very interested in how this was accomplished - OR - if anyone has been able to change the destination file name using the `Flex` `fileReference.browse()` method I would also be eternally grateful for any pointers.

---

### PHP code for this is as follows:

```
$aws_key = 'removed_for_security';
$aws_secret = 'removed_for_security';
$source_file = $uploaded_s3_file; // file to upload to S3 (defined in above script)
$aws_bucket = 'bucket'; // AWS bucket
$aws_object = $event_file_name; // AWS object name (file name)
if (strlen($aws_secret) != 40) die("$aws_secret should be exactly 40 bytes long");
$file_data = file_get_contents($source_file);
if ($file_data == false) die("Failed to read file " . $source_file);

// opening HTTP connection to Amazon S3
$fp = fsockopen("s3.amazonaws.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) die("$errstr ($errno)\n");

// Uploading object
$file_length = strlen($file_data); // for Content-Length HTTP field
$dt = gmdate('r'); // GMT based timestamp

// preparing String to Sign (see AWS S3 Developer Guide)
// preparing string to sign
$string2sign = "PUT


{$dt}
/{$aws_bucket}/{$aws_object}";

// preparing HTTP query 
// $query = "PUT /".$aws_bucket."/".$event_file_name." HTTP/1.1
$query = "PUT /" . $event_file_name . " HTTP/1.1
Host: {$aws_bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: {$dt}
x-amz-copy-source: /{$aws_bucket}/{$current_s3_filename}
x-amz-acl: public-read

Authorization: AWS {$aws_key}:" . amazon_hmac($string2sign) . "\n\n";

$query .= $file_data;
$resp = sendREST($fp, $query);
if (strpos($resp, '') !== false) {
     die($resp);
}
echo "FILE uploaded\n";

// done
echo "Your file's URL is: http://s3.amazonaws.com/{$aws_bucket}/{$aws_object}\n";
fclose($fp);

// Sending HTTP query and receiving, with trivial keep-alive support
function sendREST($fp, $q, $debug = true){
     if ($debug) echo "\nQUERY<<{$q}>>\n";
     fwrite($fp, $q);
     $r = '';
     $check_header = true;
     while (!feof($fp)) {
          $tr = fgets($fp, 256);
          if ($debug) echo "\nRESPONSE<<{$tr}>>";
          $r .= $tr;
          if (($check_header) && (strpos($r, "\r\n\r\n") !== false)) {

               // if content-length == 0, return query result
               if (strpos($r, 'Content-Length: 0') !== false) {
                    return $r;
               }
          }

          // Keep-alive responses does not return EOF
          // they end with \r\n0\r\n\r\n string
          if (substr($r, -7) == "\r\n0\r\n\r\n") {
               return $r;
          }
     }
     return $r;
}

// hmac-sha1 code START
// hmac-sha1 function: assuming key is global $aws_secret 40 bytes long
// read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC
// warning: key($aws_secret) is padded to 64 bytes with 0x0 after first function call
function amazon_hmac($stringToSign) {

     // helper function binsha1 for amazon_hmac (returns binary value of sha1 hash)
     if (!function_exists('binsha1')) {
          if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.0.0", ">=")) {
               function binsha1($d) { return sha1($d, true); }
          } else {
               function binsha1($d) { return pack('H*', sha1($d)); }
          }
     }
     global $aws_secret;
     if (strlen($aws_secret) == 40) {
          $aws_secret = $aws_secret . str_repeat(chr(0), 24);
     }
     $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), 64);
     $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), 64);
     $hmac = binsha1(($aws_secret ^ $opad) . binsha1(($aws_secret ^ $ipad) . $stringToSign));
     return base64_encode($hmac);
}
// hmac-sha1 code END
```

**When I submit a malformed or incorrect header I get the corresponding error message as expected:**

Query:

> PUT /bucket/1-132-1301047200-1.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host: s3.amazonaws.com x-amz-acl: public-read Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 34102 Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2011 00:43:36 +0000 Authorization: AWS -removed for security-:GmgRObHEFuirWPwaqRgdKiQK/EQ= 
>
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> x-amz-request-id: A7CB0311812CD721
> x-amz-id-2: ZUY0mH4Q20Izgt/9BNhpJl9OoOCp59DKxlH2JJ6K+sksyxI8lFtmJrJOk1imxM/A
> Content-Type: application/xml
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2011 00:43:36 GMT
> Connection: close
> Server: AmazonS3
> 397 SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.50 55 54 0a 0a 0a 53 61 74 2c 20 32 36 20 4d 61 72 20 32 30 31 31 20 30 30 3a 34 33 3a 33 36 20 2b 30 30 30 30 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 2f 6d 6c 68 2d 70 72 6f 64 75 63 74 69 6f 6e 2f 31 2d 31 33 32 2d 31 33 30 31 30 34 37 32 30 30 2d 31 2e 6a 70 67A7CB0311812CD721ZUY0mH4Q20Izgt/9BNhpJl9OoOCp59DKxlH2JJ6K+sksyxI8lFtmJrJOk1imxM/AGmgRObHEFuirWPwaqRgdKiQK/EQ=PUT Sat, 26 Mar 2011 00:43:36 +0000 x-amz-acl:public-read /bucket/1-132-1301047200-1.jpg-removed for security- 0

**but when sending properly formatted requests, it says I'm not authenticated:**

Query being used:

> PUT /1-132-1301047200-1.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2011 00:41:50 +0000 x-amz-copy-source: /bucket/clock.jpg x-amz-acl: public-read Authorization: AWS -removed for security-:BMiGhgbFnVAJyiderKjn1cT7cj4=
>
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> x-amz-request-id: ABE45FD4DFD19927
> x-amz-id-2: CnkMmoF550H1zBlrwwKfN8zoOSt7r/zud8mRuLqzzBrdGguotcvrpZ3aU4HR4RoO
> Content-Type: application/xml
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2011 00:41:50 GMT
> Server: AmazonS3
>
> AccessDenied
> Anonymous users cannot copy objects. Please authenticate
> ABE45FD4DFD19927CnkMmoF550H1zBlrwwKfN8zoOSt7r/zud8mRuLqzzBrdGguotcvrpZ3aU4HR4RoO 0
> Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2011 00:41:50 GMT
> Connection: close
> Server: AmazonS3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have been trying for weeks to properly format a REST request to the Amazon AWS S3 API using the available examples on the web

Have you tried the [Amazon AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)?  It's comprehensive, complete, and most importantly, written by Amazon.  If *their own code* isn't working for you, something's gonna be really wrong.

---

Here is example code using the linked SDK to upload `example.txt` in the current directory to a bucket named 'my_very_first_bucket'.

```
<?php
// Complain wildly.
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting(-1);
// Set these yourself.
    define('AWS_KEY', '');
    define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', '');
// We'll assume that the SDK is in our current directory
    include_once 'sdk-1.3.1/sdk.class.php';
    include_once 'sdk-1.3.1/services/s3.class.php';
// Set the bucket and name of the file we're sending.
// It happens that we're actually uploading the file and 
// keeping the name, so we're re-using the variable
// below.
    $bucket_name = 'my_very_first_bucket';
    $file_to_upload = 'example.txt';
// Fire up the object
    $s3 = new AmazonS3(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
// This returns a "CFResponse"
    $r = $s3->create_object(
        $bucket_name,
        $file_to_upload,
        array(
        // Filename of the thing we're uploading
            'fileUpload' => (__DIR__ . '/' . $file_to_upload),
        // ACL'd public.
            'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
        // No wai.
            'contentType' => 'text/plain',
        // The docs say it'll guess this, but may as well.
            'length' => filesize(__DIR__ . '/' . $file_to_upload)
        )
    );
// Did it work?
    echo "Worked: ";
    var_dump($r->isOK());
// Status as in HTTP.
    echo "\nStatus: ";
    var_dump($r->status);
// The public URL by which we can reach this object.
    echo "\nURL: ";
    echo $s3->get_object_url($bucket_name, $file_to_upload);
// Tada!
    echo "\n";
```

Appropriate API docs:

- [`get_object_url`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url)
- [`create_object`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/create_object)
- The [`CFResponse`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#i=CFResponse) class.

You can navigate the rest of the methods in the left menu.  It's pretty comprehensive, including new bucket creation, management, deletion, same for objects, etc.

You should be able to basically drop this in to your code and have it work properly.  PHP 5.2-safe.

---

Edit by Silver Tiger:

**Charles** - 

     The method you provide is using the API SDK functions to upload a file from the local file system to a bucket of my choosing. I have that part working already via Flex and uploads work like a charm. The problem in question is being able to submit a REST request to AWS S3 to change the file name from it's current "uploaded" name, to a new name more suited name that will work with my back end (database, tracking etc, which I handle and display seperately in PHP with MyySQL).

     AWS S3 does not truly support a "copy" function, so they provided a method to re-"PUT" a file by reading the source from your own bucket and placing a new copy with a different name in the same bucket.  The difficulty I have been having is processing the REST request, hence the HMAC encryption.

     I do appreciate your time and understand the example you have provided as i also have a working copy of the PHP upload that was functioning before I designed the Flex application. The reason for the Flex was to enable status updates and a dynamically updated progress bar, which is also working like a charm :).

I will continue to persue a REST solution as from the perspective of Amason zupport, it will be the only way i can rename a file already existing in my bucket per thier support team.

As always, if you have input or suggestions regarding the REST submission I would be greatful for any feedback.

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

---

Proof copy/delete works:

```
    $r = $s3->copy_object(
        array( 'bucket' => $bucket_name, 'filename' => $file_to_upload ),
        array( 'bucket' => $bucket_name, 'filename' => 'foo.txt' )
    );
// Did it work?
    echo "Worked: ";
    var_dump($r->isOK());
// Status as in HTTP.
    echo "\nStatus: ";
    var_dump($r->status);

// The public URL by which we can reach this object.
    echo "\nURL: ";
    echo $s3->get_object_url($bucket_name, 'foo.txt');

    echo "\nDelete: ";
// Nuke?
    $r = $s3->delete_object($bucket_name, $file_to_upload);
// Did it work?
    echo "Worked: ";
    var_dump($r->isOK());
// Status as in HTTP.
    echo "\nStatus: ";
    var_dump($r->status);
```

---

Edit by Silver Tiger:

**Charles** - 

     No REST needed, no bothers ... SDK 1.3.1 and your help solved the issue. the code I used to test looks a lot like yours :

```
// Complain wildly.
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting(-1);
// Set these yourself.
    define('AWS_KEY', 'removed for security');
    define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'removed for security');
// We'll assume that the SDK is in our current directory
    include_once 'includes/sdk-1.3.1/sdk.class.php';
    include_once 'includes/sdk-1.3.1/services/s3.class.php';
// Set the bucket and name of the file we're sending.
// It happens that we're actually uploading the file and 
// keeping the name, so we're re-using the variable
// below.
    $bucket = 'bucket';
    $file_to_upload = 'example.txt';
    $Source_file_to_copy = 'Album.jpg';
    $Destination_file = 'Album2.jpg';
// Fire up the object
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$response = $s3->copy_object(
    array( // Source
        'bucket' => $bucket,
        'filename' => $Source_file_to_copy
    ),
    array( // Destination
        'bucket' => $bucket,
        'filename' => $Destination_file
    )
);
// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

Now I will implement the delete after the copy, and we're golden. Thank you sir for your insight and help.

Silver Tiger

Comment: I have tried using the SDK as it has a signature creater, and it is where I originally started with this process ... I have even asked Amazon to help directly and they say "here, read our web page" .. so much for a paid support plan.

Comment: I'm confused, here.  Are you trying to make the S3 requests through Flex, or through PHP?

Comment: My original attempt and current succesful file upload is through Flex, but I then realized that if two people upload the same file name, it will overwrite the current file on S3. I decided to try and use a REST interface with PHP to "rename" the file but extensive attempts have failed. I was hoping to head back to the original working Flex application I had written to rename the file during upload so I could avoid the REST (PHP) solution entirely. I have not found a Flex solution, so am still persuing all avenues. REST still is failing for me. I can provide a URL to the PHP REST I am using

Comment: The actual PHP code would be far more useful than the URL to it.

Comment: the code is too long to post in a comment, I will see if I can add it as a new post on my original topic

Comment: I have added the PHP to the original post for review. One issue i have with it is that the original code called for a local file to upload. I would rather only submit the REST with the headers to copy the file on the S3 to the new file on the S3 ... but when i remove the $file_data (and remove it from the $query) the entire process hangs, from lack of content in the frwite() i presume.

Comment: I was about to go back and fix the formatting on your code, but it looks like you've HTMLized it.  Can you please re-paste it in, then select it all and click the code formatting toolbar button?  It looks like a set of curlies.

Comment: Okay, so after looking at the code for a bit, I think I see your problem: *you're needlessly reinventing the wheel*.  What PHP version are you using?  Modern PHP versions have a built-in HMAC function, for example.  I've used a few other AWS services before, but never S3.  Later today, I'm going to try and put together a quick demo that I hope will work for you, if nobody actually spots a specific problem with your code before then.

Comment: Another wheel-reinvention problem is that you're using mixed instances of CRs and CRLFs, where HTTP only thinks in CRLFs until you hit the message data.

Comment: PHP 5.2.10 (not by choice, 3rd party server) - ... Understood. I would rather have used the built in signature() function included with the AWS PHP SDK, but all the examples I have found are using more complicated call to services like EC2 (database queries etc), while all I am trying to do is a simple HTTP "PUT". I have found no examples (including the one I cannibalized for this code) that simply submit headers for the PUT (or copy in AWS S3 speak). Even this one wants me to copy the file contents and append them to the actual query, which I feel in my gut is wrong.

Comment: so all references in the submitted headers should be \r\n ? and if I am really only submitting headers to initiate an action on the S3 side - what truly is the data?

Comment: @Silvertiger, I've added an example using the SDK that should Just Work(tm) for you.  It's super-simple and straight-forward, and if you experience trouble with it, I'll eat a hat.

Comment: Apparently i was able to edit your answer, I have included some clarification above if you have time.

Comment: You should be able to do a rename by using [`copy_object`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/copy_object) to create a copy with it's own name, then using [`delete_object`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/delete_object) to remove the old one.  If you do this often, you might want to see if this ends up charging you an excessive amount of money.

Comment: the "copy object" does not work with the sdk, because since they developed the SDK they now require authenticated transactions. I tried that before .. no joy.  Like I said, I called Amazon support and they say that I can't even use SOAP, i have to use REST to submit the http header request to re-"PUT" the file in order to rename it.

Comment: That just means that it needs someone with high rep to look it over -- I've sent it through.  :)  I heartily encourage you to not build your own HTTP adapter, it's way too much work for a very small benefit.  People smarter than you and I have already built tools for us to use, we should use them!

Comment: I will gladly try the "copy_object" again .. but it didn't work before :( ... i'll try and set up a copy in the next few minutes with your setup as a guideline and test it out.

Comment: I have edited my post with tested proof that copy/delete works.  `foo.txt` is now in my management console, and `example.txt` is gone.

Comment: sorry .. at work while trying to test this for myself :) ... i'll post shortly whether I was able to duplicate your efforts

Comment: a Copy worked with the SDK... and to tell you the truth ... I was using the SDK that was available when i started this project (1.2.6) .. they must had made some changes since then, when i grabbed 1.3.1 and tried the script .. viola. You sir earn points. THANK YOU

Comment: It's great to hear you got it working!  Hopefully the comprehensive back-and-forth and edits in the answer will make this post useful for others!

Comment: actually .. Now I remember why I could not use "copy" ... when you copy a file .. it does not copy or apply the ACL, so every file you copy has the "private" acl and is not viewable to the public, the ACL is added when the REST header request is performed ... /cry

Comment: The copy method in the SDK includes the ability to set a specific ACL on the copy, as part of the options array.  Further, there are explicit methods to get and set the ACL on an object, conveniently called `get_object_acl` and `set_object_acl`.  What *isn't* immediately obvious is what data actually gets returned from the getter.  Tonight is the first time I've ever played with S3, so I'm not entirely sure how the ACLs work outside of knowing that they exist.

Comment: Crisis averted .. the command set_object_acl worked like a charm as well .. thanks much.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Excellent discussion.